# Syntax highlight for APIDoc/JSDoc in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I'm using [APIDoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vscode) to document my server side APIs.
I do so in separate .js files that are hundreds of lines long so syntax highlighting could be helpful.

It should probably look [something like this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/JsDoc-support-in-JavaScript).

Before writing a custom syntax highlighter I want to make sure I'm not missing anything though - is there a way to highlight APIDoc/JSDoc syntax already (something like [this for Atom](https://github.com/WojciechP/atom-apidocjs))?

Thanks!